# Product of two functions with opposite sense of variation

Tags: functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

I have two functions, $f$ and $g$.

- $f<0$, strictly increasing, and bounded above (by $0$).
- $g<0$, strictly decreasing, and bounded above (by $0$).

Does $fg$ admit a maximum? Here's what I tried:

Let $h=fg$. Then $h'(x)= f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x) = ``\leq 0" + ``\geq 0"$, which is inconclusive.

Comment: $f=-1/x$, $g=-\sqrt x \to h=\dfrac{-\sqrt x}{-x}=\sqrt x$ and does not have a maximum. (for $x>0$)

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar are there conditions for this to hold? For example, replacing $\sqrt{x}$ by $\sqrt{x-2}$ would make the product have a maximum.

Comment: Yes, your example has a maximum. Honestly, I did think about what you said and nothing got up. There seems to be no direct relationship between the assumptions and conclusions.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas how is it not bounded when there is no positive value for it?